# How can I hide a column with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newbie about jQuery and JavaScript. I am working on a table that contains some information but I have to hide 3 columns with all of the cells and the containing information. My JS-code is this:

```
 $.each(currentParams.columns[0], function (index, column) {
if (column.field == 'columnAdress' || column.type == 'columnTime'
    || column.type == 'columnMail' || column.type == 'columnPhone'
     || column.type == 'project') {
    column.hidden = true;
} else {
    visibleColumns++;
}
```

In the table the column is hidden but a noticeable empty space remains. This is how it looks like:

[image]

My question is: Is there a better way to do this without the remaining white space?

Comment: Will you need to later re-show the values in those columns? Otherwise I would say just delete them instead of hiding them

Comment: You have to check what causes that space. Spaces in html markup are not magic. Use your browsers console to take a look into that. Also take care to understand the difference between something "hidden" and something "transparent".

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS, otherwise we're trying to diagnose a picture, which is mostly impossible. And of little use to others in future. Take a read of the "[ask]" and "[MCVE]" guidelines, please, to explain how the question might be improved to avoid closure/'holding'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick example, visibility:hidden still takes up space on the webpage as if the element was there, display none doesn't. instead of`column.hidden = true;` use `column.hide();`

```js
$('#visibilitybutton').click(function(){
       $('#visibilityhidden').css("visibility","hidden");
                                       
                            });

$('#displaybutton').click(function(){
       $('#displaynone').hide();
                                       
                            });
```

```css
div{border:1px solid red;margin:2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>jhfbvjhfvhv</div>
<div id="visibilityhidden">lurisghselkvhlguhgww</div>
<div>jkfgbhnr;br;</div>
<div id="displaynone">jskvsr;vnoive</div>
<div>eusvhsrkvjrlkj</div>
<button id="visibilitybutton">Click to hide visibility div</button>
<button id="displaybutton">Click to hide display div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short look, If u want to hide any element you can use like this:

`$(".classname" or  "#id").hide();`

If i understand your question.. you are trying to asking question something like this... :

1st row `*`|`**`|`***`|`****`

2nd row `*`|`**`|`***`|`****`

3rd row `*`|`**`|`***`|`****`

4th row `*`|`**`|`***`|`****`

5th row `*`|`**`|`***`|`****`

`*` is first column (name)

** is second column(date)

*** is third column(etc)

**** is fourth column(etc)

and u want to hide third or fourth cloumn.
You can do something like this :

```
$(".columnclass" || "#columnid").hide();
```

For show the column

```
$(".columnclass" || "#columnid").show();
```

Please explain good your question and show your html code.